# Java - returning all elements in a BST higher than a random input

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a method which returns every element in a BST that's higher than a random input. This is what I have so far.

```
  @Override
  public SortedSet<E> tailSet(E toElement){
      SortedSet<E> set = new SearchTreeSet<>();
      tailSet(root, toElement, set);
      return set;
      }

  private void tailSet(Node<E> n, E elt, SortedSet<E> set){
      if(n == null||myCompare(n.data,elt)<0){
          return;
      }
      set.add((E) n.data);
      tailSet(n.left, elt, set);
      tailSet(n.right, elt, set);
  }
```

This works just fine when the randomly generated input is found in the BST, but when it's not I obviously get returned an empty set. The only way I can think to do this is increment the input until it finds something in the tree but that's horribly inefficient and I know there has to be a better way to go about this.

```
     if(!contains(elt)){
      while(myCompare(n.data,elt)<0){
          tailSet(n.right,elt,set);
      }
```

I have added this conditional which works but often times skips the next closest element and returns all the elements after that.

Comment: An algorithm that navigates to an entry in a BST based "value equal to `x`" can be trivially modified to navigate to "smallest value that's greater than `x`"...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so could I write a conditional where if the BST doesn't contain the elt, do a compare until I find a node that's greater than the element? i'm unsure of how else i would modify this. EDIT: I've updated with a conditional I added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for working with any random input (whether it is in the tree or not)

```
@Override
public SortedSet<T> tailSet(T fromElement) {
    Node<T> n = searchExactOrNearestSmaller(fromElement, root);
    return higherElements(n);
}   

private Node<T> searchExactOrNearestSmaller(T fromElement, Node<T> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (root.data.equals(fromElement)) {
        return root;
    }
    Node<T> x = root;
    Node<T> nextSearch = null;

    if (fromElement.compareTo(x.data) < 0) {
        nextSearch = searchExactOrNearestSmaller(fromElement, x.left);
    } else {
        nextSearch = searchExactOrNearestSmaller(fromElement, x.right);
    }
    if (nextSearch == null) {
        nextSearch = (root.data.compareTo(fromElement) > 0) ? predecessor(root) : root;
    }
    return nextSearch;
}

private SortedSet<T> higherElements(Node<T> n) {
    SortedSet<T> set = new SearchTreeSet<T>();
    Node<T> succ = successor(n);
    while (succ != null) {
        set.add((T) succ.data);
        succ = successor(succ);
    }
    return set;
}

private Node<T> successor(Node<T> n) {
    Node<T> x = n;
    if (x.right != null) {
        x = x.right;
        while (x.left != null) {
            x = x.left;
        }
        return x;
    }
    Node<T> p = x.parent;
    while (p != null && p.right == x) {
        p = p.parent;
        x = x.parent;
    }
    return p;
}

private Node<T> predecessor(Node<T> n) {
    Node<T> x = n;
    if (x.left != null) {
        x = x.left;
        while (x.right != null) {
            x = x.right;
        }
        return x;
    }
    Node<T> p = x.parent;
    while (p != null && p.left == x) {
        p = p.parent;
        x = x.parent;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Here is the Node class

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }

    Node<T> left;
    Node<T> right;
    Node<T> parent;
    T data;

}
```

Here is the code to test this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<Integer> ten = new Node<Integer>(10);
        Node<Integer> twelve = new Node<Integer>(12);
        Node<Integer> thirteen = new Node<Integer>(13);
        Node<Integer> six = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> two = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> three = new Node<Integer>(3);

        ten.left = three;
        ten.right = twelve;
        three.parent = ten;
        twelve.parent = ten;
        three.left = two;
        three.right = six;
        two.parent = three;
        six.parent = three;
        twelve.right = thirteen;
        thirteen.parent = twelve;

        SearchTreeSet<Integer> s = new SearchTreeSet<Integer>(ten);
        Set<Integer> ss = s.tailSet(3);
        for (Integer i : ss) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the test:

```
6
10
12
13
```

Comment: Please note that this solution is O(logn) in the average case and O(n) in the worst case. Like I mentioned, the one you are currently using  (scanning the entire tree) is a O(n) solution in the average and worst case

Comment: This is the definition of spoon-feeding answers. Let's try to point out errors, or help debug, not just copy-paste in a solution